# How to get unparsed HTML source code with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with Python and want to access the plain HTML source code before it is parsed and the DOM is modified by the browser. I do not want to use "driver.page_source" as it is giving me back the DOM after parsing and for example dynamically created elements are included. I know I could do a second request with for example requests but I am looking for a way to extract it without doing an additional request. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the plain HTML source by using `driver.get(f"view-source:{url}")`. Then get the body of the source using `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is also performing a second request. I was hoping to do it in a single request.

Comment: No, that's not possitble.